# browser.getProcessedConfig() not working in jenkins

Tags: typescript, jenkins, protractor, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

We have this code in protractor.conf.js file to ***get the path directory of the currently running test in protractor***. We were able to get locate successfully get the string value in local. However when creating build job in jenkins, this method returns nothing. We need to have the same exact result of this in jenkins. Any help?

```
 onPrepare() {
    return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(config => {
        return config.specs.toString();
    });
}
```

***Edit for more info:***
We have a `get` method that get a json filename from directory. Currently it's in the root directory so we just use `process.cwd()`.

Comment: what do you do with it? print it? save it?

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov i need to get the path of the currently running file and strip the string value to point out to specific path i need it to. (ex. the path of currently running file is /folder1/checkthis/here/currentlyrunning, i need this /folder1/checkthis/here/<another folder>). I can't use process.cwd() because it is incomplete. basically the complete path i need to get is process.cwd()/folder1/checkthis/here/

Comment: more details needed. In particular an example of spec file where you want this to be used

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I'm not sure what else you need. But it was being not being used by spec file but a ts file.

Comment: are you able to see the browser opening in the jenkins server where you run the test in the workspace. Also what do you get when you to try to log the value of `browser.getProcessedConfig()`

Comment: @Saravanan I'm trying to log it, im getting "undefined"

Comment: Could you add a little more info to the question? What do you mean by "get the path directory of the currently running test in protractor". Also could you post what's the difference between your set up and Jenkins that requires a folder path. Thanks!

Comment: @cnishina this is exactly what I've been trying to get in order to help for a month now. No luck so far

Comment: @MielYan it doesn't matter what extension of the file you use! we need to see how you call it. Otherwise noone will be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

if you do

```
onPrepare() {
    browser.getProcessedConfig().then(config => {
        global.currentSpec = config.specs.toString();
    });
}
```

then `currentSpec` will be available anywhere while protractor is running

```
    describe('Suite', () => {
        it('Test case', async () => {
            console.log(currentSpec)
        });
    });
```

Comment: this is working on my local but not on jenkins. :( also, im using it before this block describe('Suite', () => {

Comment: what are you doing with the `currentSpec` this may help me understand the direction to look for

Comment: I need to get the path of the currently running file and strip the string value to point out to specific path i need it to. (ex. the path of currently running file is /folder1/checkthis/here/currentlyrunning, i need this /folder1/checkthis/here/<another folder>). I can't use process.cwd() because it is incomplete. basically the complete path i need to get is process.cwd()/folder1/checkthis/here/